# Quarter tones/middle eastern scale in Logic Pro

Tags: scales, logic-pro, quarter-tones

Is it possible to set some of the tracks in Logic Pro to be quarter tones i.e. Middle Eastern sounding, while some other tracks are Western sounding?

Comment: I don't believe it will allow more than one tuning at a time.

Comment: OK that is really strange because it is quite common to mix these in "western" music.

Comment: http://www.logic-users-group.com/forums/threads/modal-scale-transpositions.8243/  This might help.  It looks like it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. Couple of possible workarounds:

Try adding a pitch modifier to a track. With the right automation you can get it to emulate the correct sound, but writing music like this tends to be terribly slow.

You'd be able to use something like [Pd](https://puredata.info/) or [Max](https://cycling74.com/shop/) and wire it up to Logic using [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/), but depending on your technical capabilities that might be a really complex way of doing what you want.